ggplot2 print stats_summary above plot in R
Is there a easy way to plot the stat_summary not within the plot but above it?
Because it takes up way to much space and until now, I did not find a solution.
This is my code so far:
stats_PFAS10_depth <- function(y, upper_limit = max(PFAS_data$pfas10) * 1.15) {
  return(data.frame(
    y = 0.95 * upper_limit,
    label = paste(
      "Anzahl =", length(y), "\n",
      "Mittelwert =", round(mean(y), 2), "\n",
      "KI1 = ", mean(y) - qnorm(0.95)*std(y)/sqrt(length(y)), "\n",
      "KI2 = ", mean(y) + qnorm(0.95)*std(y)/sqrt(length(y)), "\n",
      "1.Q = ", quantile(y, probs=0.25, na.rm=TRUE), "\n",
      "Median =", round(median(y), 2), "\n", # 2. Quantile
      "3.Q = ", quantile(y, probs=0.75,na.rm=TRUE), "\n",
      "90 % Q = ", quantile(y, probs=0.9, na.rm=TRUE), "\n",
      "Mittelwert =", round(mean(y), 2), "\n",
      "STD = ", round(std(y),2), "\n", 
      "Varianz =", round(var(y),2), "\n",
      "Max =", round(max(y),2), "\n",
      "Min =", round(min(y),2), "\n"
    )
  ))
}

PFAS_data %>%
  mutate(Quelle = factor(Quelle, levels=c('Siedlung', 'Hauptpunktquelle'))) %>%
  mutate(Probenart = factor(Probenart, levels=c('OBER-0-20', 'UNTER20-40'))) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = pfas10, y = Probenart))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Probenart), col = "black", outlier.size = 2, outlier.shape = 1, width=0.5, na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_jitter(width  = 0.1, color = "grey46" )+
  facet_grid(~ Quelle, scale = "free", space = "free") +
  stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar', width = 0.2) +  
  stat_summary(fun.data = stats_PFAS10_depth, geom = "text", hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=11),axis.text.x =element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14), axis.text.y =element_text(size=12),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                         colour ="black")) +
  theme(text=element_text(family="sans")) # serif/mono/ sans

Can someone help?

Make your code reproducible by including a sample of your data using dput()

One option would be to create your table of summary stats as a separate ggplot and glue it to the main plot using patchwork:
Using some fake random example data:
set.seed(123)

PFAS_data <- expand.grid(
  Quelle = c("Siedlung", "Hauptpunktquelle"),
  Probenart = c("OBER-0-20", "UNTER20-40"),
  id = seq_len(20)
)

PFAS_data <- PFAS_data |>
  transform(pfas10 = rnorm(nrow(PFAS_data)))

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

stats_PFAS10_depth <- function(y) {
  data.frame(
    value = c(
      length(y),
      round(mean(y), 2),
      mean(y) - qnorm(0.95) * sd(y) / sqrt(length(y)),
      mean(y) + qnorm(0.95) * sd(y) / sqrt(length(y)),
      quantile(y, probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
      round(median(y), 2), # 2. Quantile
      quantile(y, probs = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
      quantile(y, probs = 0.9, na.rm = TRUE),
      round(mean(y), 2),
      round(sd(y), 2),
      round(var(y), 2),
      round(max(y), 2),
      round(min(y), 2)
    ),
    stat = c(
      "Anzahl",
      "Mittelwert",
      "KI1",
      "KI2",
      "1.Q",
      "Median",
      "3.Q",
      "90 % Q",
      "Mittelwert",
      "STD",
      "Varianz",
      "Max",
      "Min"
    )
  ) |>
    transform(stat = factor(stat, levels = rev(unique(stat))))
}

PFAS_data <- PFAS_data |>
  mutate(
    Quelle = factor(Quelle, levels = c("Siedlung", "Hauptpunktquelle")),
    Probenart = factor(Probenart, levels = c("OBER-0-20", "UNTER20-40"))
  )

p_main <- PFAS_data |>
  ggplot(mapping = aes(y = pfas10, x = Probenart)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Probenart),
    col = "black",
    outlier.size = 2, outlier.shape = 1, width = 0.5, na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, color = "grey46") +
  facet_grid(~Quelle, scale = "free", space = "free") +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 11), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    legend.background = element_rect(
      size = 0.5, linetype = "solid",
      colour = "black"
    ),
    text = element_text(family = "sans"),
    plot.margin = margin()
  )
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_rect()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.

p_table <-
  PFAS_data |>
  reframe(
    stats_PFAS10_depth(pfas10),
    .by = c(Quelle, Probenart)
  ) |>
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Probenart, y = stat)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = round(value, 2))
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL) +
  facet_grid(~Quelle, scale = "free", space = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 11),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = margin()
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL)

p_table /
  (p_main + theme(
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  ))


